# JavaScript stack, LIFO stack: value not as expected

Tags: javascript, stack

I have the following code.

```
var stackMapIn = [];
var stackMapOut = [];
var stackBack = [];

stackMapOut.push("m1");

$scope.clickLinks = function(initialOut,initialIn,extra,backIn,backOut,name){
        $('div#'+initialOut+'Map,'+extra).fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $('.'+initialOut+'Details,.bkbtn'+backOut).css("display","none");
            $('.'+initialIn+'Details,.bkbtn'+backIn).css("display","block");
            $('.noQuery').css("display","none");
            $("#buildingHeader").html(name);
            $('div#'+initialIn+'Map').fadeIn('slow');
        })

    stackMapOut.push(initialIn);
    stackMapIn.push(initialOut);
    stackBack.push(backIn);
}

$scope.clickBack = function(bkbtnCheck){
    alert(stackBack[0]);
    mapOut = stackMapOut.pop();
    mapIn = stackMapIn.pop();
    stackBack.pop();
    backIn = stackBack[0];
    alert(backIn);

    $('div#'+mapOut+'Map').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('.'+ mapOut + 'Details,.bkbtn').css("display", "none");
        $('.' + mapIn + 'Details,.bkbtn'+backIn).css("display", "block");
        $(".noQuery").css("display","none");
        $("#buildingHeader").html("Name");
        $('div#' + mapIn + 'Map').fadeIn('slow');
    })
}
```

Now I am going to do a quick run-through of what happens as this code runs.

The first time clickLinks runs:

> initialIn = 'm2'
>
> initialOut = 'm1'
>
> backIn = 'Home'

*clickBack* has not run yet.

The second time *clickLinks* runs:

> initialIn = 'm7'
>
> initialOut = 'm2'
>
> backIn = 'CentralPortfolio'

Ok so at this point things should be looking like this (I expect):

> stackMapOut = ['m1','m2','m7']
>
> stackMapIn = ['m1','m2']
>
> stackback = ['Home','CentralPortfolio']

Now we run *clickBack*... Why does the alert output "Home"??

What I am trying to do here is, I have a series of things appearing and disappearing when *clickLinks* runs. Sometimes, the user can run *clickBack* in order to return to the previous state(status). So, I am using **JavaScript stack** to keep track of what state it is on and thus where it needs to return.

The problem is, I can run *clickLinks* once, clickBack once consecutively without issue. I can even run *clickLinks* a second time and still click the back button 2 times (to return to start) without issue. But I still don't understand why **stackBack[0]** (which should be the top of the stack ?) **= "Home"** at this point instead of "CentralPortfolio".

Because the real problem that I run into is now if I run *clickLinks* a third time: still **stackBack[0] = 'Home'** (when I expect it to be 'CentralCampus' at this point) and thus, it is the "Home" back button that is showing (while the correct other stuff is showing in accordance to *mapOut* and *mapIn*) instead of CentralPortfolio' back button to be showing; since I have 'CentralCampus' "popped" off before I use it.

---

Please, if any other information is needed or you need more clarification let me know. I tried my best to provide any needed information and make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now we run clickBack... Why does the alert output "Home"??`

because `stackBack[0]` is `Home`. What would you expect it to do? You even have it in your question:

```
stackback = ['Home','CentralPortfolio']
```

The index `0` is the first element in your array, which is `Home`. The last element is `stackBack[stackBack.length - 1]`

> using JavaScript stack

No, you are using a javascript array, but using it like a stack. Except when you index it like an array - which is the root of your confusion. You can use it as a stack with `pop` and `push`, but then don't try and index it with `[]`

When you `push` on an array, you add an element to *the end* of the array. In other words, it ends up as the last element at the index `yourArray.length - 1`. When you `pop`, you take that last element off the array again. So popping `stackback` would give you back `CentralPortfolio`, and, of course, the first element is unchanged.

Comment: Well that's what I get for working my brain to mush. I knew I had to have been confusing part of the concept of this! Even though, I seemingly understood it by explaining what the array contains correctly! For some reason I at the same time thought [0] was the current value, [0] is the FIRST value, I need the last value! Thank you!